# In Jmeter, how to control the throughput of transaction controller as a whole instead of as individual sampler?

Tags: jmeter

I have a transaction controller in Jmeter which consists of 4 samplers. From business perspective I see these 4 samplers together as an atomic transaction, and I want to control the throughput of this transaction in Jmeter run.

However if I add constant throughput timer for the transaction controller and run, I see that the throughput timer applies to sampler, e.g. if throughput timer is 1/minute, then instead of finishing 1 transaction (4 samplers) per minute, Jmeter runs 1 sampler per minute, which is 1 transaction per 4 minutes.

So what can I do to make it right? Either via throughput timer, throughput controller, or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter Timers are executed before each [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) in their [Scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules). See [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer) for more details.

If you need to execute 1 transaction per minute configure the [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) "Target throughput" to be `4`, in this case a Sampler will be executed each 15 seconds which will give you "1 transaction per minute". If you want 1 transaction per 4 minutes - reduce the "Target throughput" accordingly.

Or alternatively tick "Generate parent sample" box and in this case the Constant Throughput Timer will be applied to the "synthetic" sampler

[image]

Comment: this constant throughput timer does not work with less than 1 value? e.g. my throughput expectation is 1 transaction per 5 minutes, but if i put target throughput (in samples per minute) as 0.2. it does not run the transaction at all